# Viber sounds distorted when i get a new message

Tags: viber

On my laptop only Viber sounds are distorted. And that is only if viber is in stand by. But if i get more messages it gets better. (after 3-4 messages)

What can I do to fix this.

[Click to hear the sound](https://clyp.it/qjo4ajwd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer here: [LINK](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304377)

```
You have to modify the following line in /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-udev-detect
with :
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0


This is exactly what solved my problem.
```